# How to skip well-formed for java DOM parser

Tags: java, dom, saxparser, domparser

I know this has been asked multiple times here, but I've a different issue dealing with it. In my case, the app receives a non well-formed dom structure passed as a string. Here's a sample :

```
<div class='video yt'><div class='yt_url'>http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U_QLu_Twd0g&feature=abcde_gdata</div></div>
```

As you can see, the content is not well-formed. Now, if I try to parse using a normal SAX or DOM parse it'll throw an exception which is understood.

**org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The reference to entity "feature" must end with the ';' delimiter.**

As per the requirement, I need to read this document,add few additional div tags and send the content back as a string. This works great by using a DOM parser as I can read through the input structure and add additional tags at their required position.

I tried using tools like JTidy to do a pre-processing and then parse, but that results in converting the document to a fully-blown html, which I don't want. Here's a sample code :

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
Tidy tidy = new Tidy(); // obtain a new Tidy instance
tidy.setXHTML(true);
tidy.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(content.getBytes()), writer);
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(writer.toString().getBytes()));
// Traverse thru the content and add new tags
....
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

This completely converts the input to a well-formed html document. It then becomes hard to remove html tags manually. The other option I tried was to use SAX2DOM, which too creates a HTML doc. Here's a sample code .

```
ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(content.getBytes());     
Parser p = new Parser();
p.setFeature(IContentExtractionConstant.SAX_NAMESPACE,true);
SAX2DOM sax2dom = new SAX2DOM();
p.setContentHandler(sax2dom);
p.parse(new InputSource(is));
Document doc = (Document)sax2dom.getDOM();
```

I'll appreciate if someone can share their ideas.

Thanks

Comment: did you try using [Xerces2](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/) for parsing the DOM it has many attributes related to validation and parsing. A quick look shows you can define a handler to be called when encountering built-in refs (&...) which may be used to fix the above problem. [link](http://apache.org/xml/features/scanner/notify-builtin-refs)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can define your own error handler for a SAX parser

Comment: Not related to your question: you should consider to use `new StringReader(string)` instead of `new ByteArrayInputStream(string.getBytes())`. It's unnecessary to retrieve the bytes from the string, and you can also get in some troubles with the encoding. Usually you have the chance to use a `Reader` instead of an `InputStream`.

Comment: I'm not clear what's wrong with an HTML doc. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Alochi..thanks for looking. There's nothing wrong with the HTML doc,unfortunately, the requirement specs that the app should return a set of <divs> as opposed to wrapped in a html or xml structure.Since JTidy creates a HTML doc,I'll then need a post processor to remove the html tags injected by JTidy.

Comment: @javanna...thanks for the suggestion, I totally agree that StringReader shoulb be the way...thanks

Comment: @Richard .. thanks for your reply.After exploring all the possibilities and going through all the suggestions here, I think, writing a custom error handler is the only solution in this scenario.

Comment: @Asaf...thanks for the suggestion.I think I'm heading towards writing my own error handler to deal with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is replacing xml reserved characters with the corresponding xml entities. You can do this manually:

```
content.replaceAll("&", "&amp;");
```

If you don't want to modify your string before parsing it, I could propose you another way using `SaxParser`, but this solution is more complicated. Basically you have to:

1. write a `LexicalHandler` in
   combination with `ContentHandler`
2. tell the parser to continue its
   execution after fatal error (the
   `ErrorHandler` isn't enough)
3. treat undeclared entities as simple
   text

**UPDATE**
According to your comment, I'm going to add some details regarding the second solution. I've writed a class which extends `DefaulHandler` (default implementation of `EntityResolver`, `DTDHandler`, `ContentHandler` and `ErrorHandler`) and implements `LexicalHandler`. I've extended `ErrorHandler`'s `fatalError` method (my implementations does nothing instead of throwing the exception) and `ContentHandler`'s `characters` method which works in combination with `startEntity` method of `LexicalHandler`.

```
public class MyHandler extends DefaultHandler implements LexicalHandler {

    private String currentEntity = null;

    @Override
    public void fatalError(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {
        String content = new String(ch, start, length);
        if (currentEntity != null) {
            content = "&" + currentEntity + content;
            currentEntity = null;
        }
        System.out.print(content);
    }

    @Override
    public void startEntity(String name) throws SAXException {
        currentEntity = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void endEntity(String name) throws SAXException {
    }

    @Override
    public void startDTD(String name, String publicId, String systemId)
            throws SAXException {
    }

    @Override
    public void endDTD() throws SAXException {
    }

    @Override
    public void startCDATA() throws SAXException {
    }

    @Override
    public void endCDATA() throws SAXException {
    }

    @Override
    public void comment(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
    }
}
```

This is my main which parses your xml not well formed. It's very important the `setFeature`, because without it the parser throws the `SaxParseException` despite of the `ErrorHandler` empty implementation.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException,
        SAXException, IOException {
    String xml = "<div class='video yt'><div class='yt_url'>http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U_QLu_Twd0g&feature=abcde_gdata</div></div>";
    SAXParser saxParser = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser();
    XMLReader xmlReader = saxParser.getXMLReader();
    MyHandler myHandler = new MyHandler();
    xmlReader.setContentHandler(myHandler);
    xmlReader.setErrorHandler(myHandler);
    xmlReader.setProperty("http://xml.org/sax/properties/lexical-handler",
            myHandler);
    xmlReader.setFeature(
            "http://apache.org/xml/features/continue-after-fatal-error",
            true);
    xmlReader.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
}
```

This main prints out the content of your div element which contains the error:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U_QLu_Twd0g&feature=abcde_gdata
```

Keep in mind that this is an example which works with your input, maybe you'll have to complete it...for instance if you have some characters correctly escaped you should add some lines of code to handle this situation etc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I didn't want to take the first route since it becomes a very specific one parsing criteria which is caused by &. There might be more. StringUtils won't work here since it'll try to transform everything in its way. For e.g. after conversion, the original string will turn into --> &lt;div class=&apos;video yt&apos;&gt;&lt;div class=&apos;yt_url&apos;&gt;http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U_QLu_Twd0g&amp;feature=abcde_gdata&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt; Maybe I should look into the LexicalHandler option as suggested by you.

Comment: @javanna..thnx a ton for taking the time to provide the code. I'll work on it and let you know. Regarding StringEscapeUtils, I would ideally like to have it as the solution, but not sure if it works for the example I've provided. The parser won't be able to parse the resulting content from StringEscapeUtils. Can you let me know how it fits in my case ? I'm curious to know if I'm missing on something.

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right, the StringEscapeUtils#escapeXml doesn't work for you! You have just to replace the &, not < and >. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Shamik: Hi, sorry for the confusion...have you solved? Wasn't my answer helpful?

Comment: Sorry, should have got back to you on this early.Based on my requirement,I eventually settled on the second approach of using jTidy.Once the document is generated,I used xpath to extract the content.In my scenario,the input data is guaranteed to be small, so performance overhead for additional xpath process is not a concern.I was not very confident on writing a custom error handler since I was not sure of the exact scope of changes to handle different error sceanrios. But this is surely a possible way to deal with the issue.